# Chrome is guessing HTML entities?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, loops, html-entities

I have a simple function that mimics the "ellipses" effect on the end of text as a cross browser solution. The function removes 2 characters from the end of the text and sees if there is still an overflow. If there is, the function continues executing, if not, the function returns. We can find these functions all over the place and its simple enough.

I've encountered a problem, at *least* in Chrome (haven't bothered with others yet) where if the text has an HTML entity (in my particular case "&amp") the browser is "guessing" the entity, even though the entire entity is complete.

**EXAMPLE**

Here would be a sample console.log of the text as the function executes...

```
"hey mike &amp; u..."

"hey mike &amp;..."

"hey mike &am..."

"hey mike &amp;..."

"hey mike &am..."

"hey mike &amp;..."
```

As you can see, once we get to the entity, whatever it may be, is guessing the entity once the text gets inserted back into the DOM. This obviously results in a never ending loop.

Any thoughts?

**EDIT**

I've *solved* the problem by using text() instead of html() in the code below, yet it still doesn't answer the question as to why the browser (or something else) guessing the entity...

```
while($this[0].scrollHeight>$this.outerHeight() && $this.html().length){
      // var text = $this.html() *old method, with error*
      var text = $this.text();
      $this.html(text.substr(0,text.length-5)+"...");
}
```

Comment: Showing code would help.

Comment: You'll need to post your ellipsis code in order to get an answer.

Comment: Why not just use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`? It's [supported on all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow), even IE at least as far back as IE7

Comment: What browser are you supporting that is not covered here: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-overflow